# AIR - Disable context menu

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm building an app with an image upload function. While the uploading process is on I need to disable the context menu (right-click) or at least the items in it.
How to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d00.html

This answers your questions... look at Customizing the context menu paragraph

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with [this method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html#removeAllItems%28%29)? this should remove all the elements in your menu.

Hope this helps